# How to pass axios response to function argument?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, axios, nuxt.js

There is a process of acquiring user's data as follows, and storing the post data of the user in the object.
Also trying to store the first comment of the post in the post object.

```
getLatestCommentData(dataList) {
  if (dataList.length === 0) {
    return {}
  } else {
    return {
      body: dataList[0].body,
      created_at: dataList[0].created_at
    }
  }
},

async fetchUserInfo({ commit, dispatch }, { userId }) {
  const user = await this.$axios.$get(`/users/${userId}`)
  await Promise.all([
    this.$axios.$get(`users/${userId}/posts`).then(async posts => {
      user.posts = await Promise.all(
        posts.map(async post => ({
          ...post,
          latestComment: await dispatch(
            'getLatestCommentData',
            this.$axios.$get(`/posts/${post.id}/comment`)
          )
        }))
      )
    })
  ]).then(() => {
    commit('setUserInfo', user)
  })
},
```

However, in the case of the above code, the contents of the `dataList` argument of`getLatestCommentData` is as follows, and it does not work well.

```
{ dispatch: [Function],
  commit: [Function],
  getters: { mainUser: [Getter] },
  state: { mainUser: {} },
  rootGetters: { .... },
  rootState:{ .... } },
```

How can I pass the axios response data to `dataList`?

Comment: What is `getLatestCommentData`? Is it a Vuex action? You seem to be trying to dispatch it so I assume it is. If so, the first argument should be the Vuex _context_, followed by the payload. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Answer (score 0):

Use getLatestCommentData like a function. Declare it:

```
function getLatestCommentData(dataList) {
  if (dataList.length === 0) {
    return {}
  } else {
    return {
      body: dataList[0].body,
      created_at: dataList[0].created_at
    }
  }
}
```

And use it somewhere later:

```
posts.map(async (post) => ({
  ...post,
  latestComment: getLatestCommentData(await this.$axios.$get(`/posts/${post.id}/comment`))
  })
);
```